# What is the most elegant way to sort ranges in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to sort a table of objects of type `Range`by their start point. For that I have the following code which works fine:

```
ranges = @ranges.sort do |a,b|
  (a.min) <=> (b.min)
end
```

I was just wondering if there was a shorter and elegant way to do the same thing.

Comment: I don't think this question is really on-topic, since you are just asking for someone to refactor ***working code***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
ranges = @ranges.sort_by(&:min)
```

Or if you actually mean the starting point rather than the minimum, since ranges such as `(5..3)` can exist:

```
ranges = @ranges.sort_by(&:first)
```

Comment: I would avoid the first because of an edge case: `a = [4..6, 5..3];  a.sort_by(&:first) #=> [4..6, 5..3]; a.sort_by(&:min) #=> ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed`.